# How to check file exist or not in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please tell me how to check if a file exists or not in javascript? Actually I'm using `Fileserver.js`. When run, it creates a file named `"a.txt"`. When I run it again, it creates: `a.txt(1)` [`a.txt(2)`...]. I want to check if the file exists so it can ask the user if they want to overwrite the file (if the file exists).

http://jsfiddle.net/zrnQR/1/

```
$(function(){
    var blob = new Blob([ "iiiiiii" ], {
        type : "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
    });
    saveAs(blob, 'a,txt');
});
```

I googled to find it, but it's giving false every time.
http://jsfiddle.net/zrnQR/4/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if file exists in jQuery or JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript) and [Check if a file exists locally using javascript ONLY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115141/check-if-a-file-exists-locally-using-javascript-only)

Comment: i check the stackoverflow please http://jsfiddle.net/zrnQR/4/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ajax request to server to find out if the file exists.

Demo:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.yoururl.com/path/file.txt',
    type: 'GET',
    error: function()
    {
        //not exists
    },
    success: function()
    {
        // exists
    }
});
```

Hope to solve your problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zrnQR/4/

Comment: not working I checking this..please check this fiddle

Comment: what to write in  url: 'http://www.yoururl.com/path/file.txt',

Comment: it is downloading in this path C:\Users\asd\Downloads

Comment: Do you mean to detact the file you have save in local? If so, you should try the html 5 file api.But html5 has the compatibility issues in browser。 [FileApi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

```
function UrlExists(url)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('GET', url, false);
    http.send();
    if(http.readyState==4){  
    if(http.status==200)s+=" exists."; 
    else if(http.status==404)s+=" doesn't exist.";  
    else s+="";//any other status    
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net/zrnQR/4 – it is not working ..I checking anwer

Comment: can you provide fiddle

Comment: @user2535959 - you can only use Ajax to the same domain as the host page so a solution like this has to work only on the same domain (this is called same-origin restrictions).  No jsFiddle you create will work with your file on your domain because it's on a different domain.

Comment: Mean I need only check on my computer ?

Comment: @jfriend00 can you provinde a simple example which is working on your pc using filesaver.js it will take around 5 min

Comment: @user2535959 - if you're trying to check for the existence of a file on your own PC, you can't do that (for security reasons).  These ajax-based solutions (none of which I wrote - I'm just commenting here) only work to check for a file on the same server that hosts your web page.

Comment: ok...can we check on server ? not on pC

Comment: @user2535959 You can call a server side script (eg. PHP) using AJAX, and make the server code check it for you.