# Validate a file exists

Tags: javascript

I want to validate the existence of a HTML file before opening it in a new tab.

How can I do so using pure JavaScript?

I am storing the file's location in path variable.

```
path = "F:\Folder_JS\File1.html";
//I want to check here whether there exists such a file or not before opening it new tab
myWindow = window.open(path,'_blank');
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Check if a file exists locally using javascript ONLY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115141/check-if-a-file-exists-locally-using-javascript-only)

Answer (score 0):

**You may try it by js:**

```
var url = 'File1.html'; //use file url not real path. ex: folder/File1.html
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('HEAD', url, false);
http.send();
if(http.status!=404){
    //file exist
}else{
    //file not exist
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this but it keeps on generating an error

Comment: Error: Access to restricted URI denied

Comment: I think the method XMLHttpRequest is deprecated

Comment: You have to do it from server. Because js don't support cross domain. you have to execute in server.

Comment: I want to check it locally, not on server and I don't think there is a way of doing so