# IF File Exists Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Can anyone see anything wrong with this? It stops the image changing when the image is not here as I want but it does not change the image all the time when it does!

Cheers, 
Shaun

```
var myFile = "/_images/multi/" + productCode + "/" + imgCodeAlt + "_l.jpg";
if (myFile.exists()) {
    $("#imgMain img").attr({
        rel: 'lightbox',
        src: "/_images/multi/" + productCode + "/" + imgCodeAlt + "_l.jpg"
    });
}
```

Comment: I read somewhere on here that it was a function ??

Comment: there is no exists() in JS since it is client side..

Comment: @ShaunHogg: Not in JavaScript.

Comment: `@`Shaun: You read wrong. You're calling `exists()` on a ***string***, not a file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if file exists in jQuery or Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work if you define `exists` like this:

```
String.prototype.exists = function() {
    var a = new XMLHttpRequest;
    a.open( "GET", this+"", false );
    a.send( null );
    return a.status === 200;
};

"/".exists() //true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't check for files existing in Javascript due to it being a client side language.

You could try an ajax request to the file, and if it returns a 404 status code, the file does not exist - seems messy though.

Comment: JavaScript is not a client-side language. It's true that the OP is *using* it client-side in this case, though.

Comment: You can also create a `new Image()`, set the `src`, and listen for the `onerror` event.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder spot on - but having seeing his initial code i tried to keep my answer simple...

Comment: @Dennis i tried to provide a very rough solution to maybe help them them on their way...

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a exists function in javascript which can check if a file exists on some location. If you really want to check existence of file the only way you can do it in js is using ajax. check this post [How do I check if file exists in jQuery or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

What is `exists()` for? If you're trying to check if the file exists from JavaScript, then this isn't going to work using that method in JS.

I would suggest using an AJAX call if you need to verify the existence of a file.