# How to detect whether an image exists in the server using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I check if file exists in jQuery or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript)

I need to find out image exists at specific path on server using javascript.

If the image exists at specific path on server in that case I need to display a default image without showing an error.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You can use the alt property in the image tag to display a little text if the image cannot be displayed.

Comment: I used img.height to detect the height and find whethere it exists in the server. But when I refresh all the other images were taken as not exists and all the images were replaced with the default image.

Answer (score 3):

You can send an Ajax request for that image. I'll use jQuery for simplicity

```
var request = $.ajax("http://www.goggle.com/fdsf.png")​​​​​​​​​​​​​;

request.done(function(msg) {
  console.log("Exists");
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  // You check the jqXHR status object for the HTTP status so you can know 
  // why it failed
  console.log("Doesn't");
});​
```