# javascript print variable1 || variable2

Tags: javascript

I have a file that has an extention either:

```
.doc or .docx
```

I wanted to link it this way:

```
document.getElementById("file").innerHTML = "View file sent <a href='../folder/filename" +
(what syntax do I need to add here if I wanted to print which extention file is exist on that folder)
```

In PHP we can do this

```
var1 = ".doc";
var2 = ".docx";

var1 ? var1 : var2;
```

What is the equivalent of this in JavaScript?

Comment: That's not how it's done in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing here:

```
var1=".doc";
var2=".docx";

var1? var1 : var2;
```

This will always return ".doc" because var1 will always evaluate to true, regardless of whether you're using PHP or Javascript.

---

It sounds like you might be after something like this instead:

```
// this function is from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3646923/1188942
function UrlExists(url)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status!=404;
}

var ext;
if (UrlExists("http://www.mywebsite.com/folder/file.doc"))
    ext = ".doc";
else
    ext = ".docx";
```

Answer (score 3):

### Tertiary operator in JavaScript

Tertiary operators **do** exist in JavaScript:

```
var var1=".doc";
var var2=".docx";

alert(var1 ? var1 : var2);​
```

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/gRMf2/

It will work as this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gRMf2/1/)):

```
alert(var1 ? var1 : var2);​
```

### Working with undefined variables

However, if `var1` can be undefined, you will get an error (proof: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gRMf2/3/)). In such case writing this will solve the issue (proof: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gRMf2/2/)):

```
alert(typeof var1 !== 'undefined' ? var1 : var2);​
```

Answer (score 3):

In javascript, `var1 || var2` is same as php's `var1 ? var1 : var2`.

```
document.getElementById("file").innerHTML = "View file sent <a href='../folder/filename" + (var1 || var2);
```

Comment: In fact `var1 ? var1 : var2` is valid also in JavaScript. And there is one little difference: in PHP undefined first variable (like `$var1` in `$var1 ? $var1 : $var2`) will just be assumed false-ish, and will throw you a notice (if you will enable notices), while in JavaScript your script will just break.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has no access to the file system. Even if it did, it would be the end-user's local file system. You will need to check that the file exists in PHP (or whatever server-side language you choose to use).

Answer (score 0):

This is quite similar in Javascript:

```
var doc = ".doc";
var docx = ".docx";
var ext = doc ? doc : docx;
alert(ext);
```