# jQuery: .load() getting no response

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple HTML page with these jQuery statements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myDiv').load('mypage.html');
});
```

For some reason this doesn't load any HTML to the div. I used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript) to make sure the source file exists - everything checks out fine. I tried using the error callback on `.load()` and the status is "error", but the response is empty. Looking at the console I see the following GET request:

```
[12:18:20.770] GET http://localhost/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
```

Finally, when I do a simple `$('#myDiv').html('test');` it loads fine, so I know the div is set up properly.

Can anyone think of what's going wrong here? I'm running WAMP on Windows, if that's any help.

Comment: Have you tried logging what is returned by the load?

Comment: Response return in 0ms , it might be loading  from cache. you should clean your cache once.

Comment: Are you able to load the 'mypage.html' as a standalone page?

Comment: have u tried connecting load to a controller so the controller can provide the html page to be loaded?

Comment: php controller should have something like `echo(file_get_contents($URL));`, if you're new to PHP, I suggest [***Codeigniter***](http://codeigniter.com/)

Comment: I logged the response which was empty. Is there something else I can log?

Comment: I tried clearing the cache, still getting an empty response at 0ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('#myDiv').load('/root/folder/mypage.html');
```

also try.

```
$('#myDiv').html('Did i disappear?');
$('#myDiv').load('/root/folder/mypage.html');
///// Is myDiv empty when the page loads?
```

Comment: The .html() before the .load() made it work! I'm curious though... why do I need that?

Comment: `$('button').click(function(){  
  $('#content').load('hi.html');
 });`

Comment: Thats really odd. Can you try creating a new div and try .load into that div as well. So we want to try and do .load into 2 seperate divs.

Comment: I made a new div and tried a simple .html() on it. The content will change for as long as my browser status is "waiting for localhost" and then reverts back to the original text. Looks just like a refresh, but I'm not doing anything like that in the script.

Comment: Well sorry we couldn't find the exact answer.