# Check if file exists and return mime type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, html5-audio

First off please keep the following in mind: I don't not have access to PHP or any server side programming languages, trust me I really wish I did because with php this would be easy. Now onto the question.

Alright, so my users can enter there own path to a mp3 file for example they could enter

```
- Music/F07/CTDV.mp3
- Music/F12/VTGH.mp3
- Songs/rock your world.mp3
```

This information is stored in separate variables such as `song1` `song3` `song2`
I want to check and make sure that these files exists and that they are an mp3 file.

I was reading that I may be able to accomplish this using ajax, but I don't know how.

Please keep in mind this is a question, I understand it my not be possible and I accept this, if you vote it down please tell me why so I understand. Thank you.

**So the question is:** Can I use ajax/javascript to not only check if a file exists but if it is an mp3? (Files are located on sever not locally)

Comment: As in check if it exists on their computer's file system?  I'm almost positive you can't do that with javascript for security reasons.

Comment: are these files on users computer? or these are on server?

Comment: They are on the server (Updated question to clarify what I am asking and to point out they are located on the server.) @Alireza41 Thanks for asking, I always for get a detail like that.

Comment: If the files are on your server – can’t you just offer the user a list of files to chose from, instead of having them type in a name themselves?

Comment: you can use ajax to send files path to the server and check file exists or not server side and response the result. so you need to use server side language to check it.

Comment: @Cbroe I can not use any server side languages to loop though directories to find files, the user has to enter it. I just want to add a check in case they enter an invalid path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question on SO that might be of help.

[How do I check if file exists in jQuery or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript)

I have not tested this and I am not sure if it will actually find the file, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you, Ill go test it now and see what happens.