# "If default.html exists within folder then" function

Tags: jquery, directory

Is there an easy way to script a function based off a file existing or not in a particular folder? Perhaps running a 404 test against the folder?

For example:

If default.html exists in child directory preview, then do this ... else do this ...?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function exists(url) {
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'HEAD',
        async: false,
        url: url
    });

    return request.status === 200;
}
```

I wouldn't use this, however. It's a blocking call and will momentarily lock up the browser. Use the `error` callback of the `ajax` function and make the request asynchronous:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: url
}).fail(function(request, status, error) {
    // Error
}).done(function(data, status, request) {
    // Success
});
```

Better yet, don't do this at all.