# How to replace non-existing images with a default one in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a table of 10 rows which has an image of a user in first column:

```
<table>
  <tr><td><img src='images/35067.png'/></td></tr>
  <tr><td><img src='images/35089.png'/></td></tr>
  .... <!-- more rows -->
</table>
```

the image file name is generated by the [id] of its data record within mysql.
some users have no image assigned to them and the file dose not exists in the [images/] path.
i would like to replace the invalid images with a default existing image like

```
src='images/default.png'
```

i have some conditions that the action must be done on the client side, not on server-side and it could be done aether with CSS or java-script.

Comment: If you have to do it from client side, then maybe you have to check if that file exist using JavaScript. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3646923/1706309) will help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work

```
<img src='images/35067.png' onerror='this.src="images/default.png"'/>
```