# jquery simplest way to check if a file on remote server exists or not

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

I need to check if a file on a remote server exists of not. I don't have control over the remote server. The file that my javascript code is trying to check its existence can be downloaded or viewed by anyone in any web browser by typing file location on the web browser's address bar like [this sample image file](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/1682/hkt3.png)
. I tried [Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript) but always showing error.

EDIT : Remote server is on the different domain.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://public.url/sample.wav',
            type: 'HEAD',
            //dataType: 'jsonp',
            //crossDomain:true,
            error: function () {
                $("#soundFile").attr("src", "Images/error.png");                        
            },
            success: function () {
                $("#soundFile").attr("src", "Images/check.png");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Maybe it is because of the absolute path? Have you tried a relative path?

Comment: Remote server is on the different domain.

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to do that.

Comment: so cross domain is not supported for javascript . you have to goto your server and then making a request to the remote server...