# Get elements that did not load

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to find out all elements that did not load because the resource wasn't found?

```
    <body>
       <img src="notThere.png">
       <script src="notInHere.png"></script>
       <img src="DoesExist.png">

       // want to find the first and the script with unexisting sources, but not the second image with an existing source.

    </body>
```

Can somebody give me a hint how to find out those elements?
I think, setting `onerror` for each element is no solution because the elements may be loaded dynamically..

Unfortunately, `window.onerror` is not fired on 'resource not found' errors.

Example:

```
    <body>
        <script src="someonesScript.js"></script> <!-- this script might load images/audio etc.. -->
        <script>
           // now put here whatever you like
           // but find out which resources (images,scripts,..) were tried to load (from the script above)
           // and can't be loaded    

        </script>
    </body>
```

Hope this example will help to understand my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "elements may be loaded dynamically"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if an image is loaded (no errors) in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript)

Comment: What do you mean "dynamically", either you load them or you don't, if they fail they will trigger the onerror event, no other way to magically figure out if it failed to load ?

Comment: @adeneo or an other script loads them ;) like _google adsense_ which is loading a huge number of resources; i even don't know which resources were tried to load..

Comment: @Dave the difference: i even don't know which resources were tried to load, because they might be loaded by other scripts etc.. But yeah, I have read this post before; but i cant use it in my case.

Comment: At a minimum, you need to put your error-catching code first. Before you actually try to load anything. Unless you go with the instant-in-time option, in which case it needs to be last, and after the document is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is theoretically possible with the `error` event and bubbling (the `error` event should bubble), sadly browser support for it is weak (to say the least)

At best, you could loop through the DOM at a particular instant and look for all `src` attributes, and check if they point to valid resources (by the methods which others have suggested). But that won't catch anything which has been removed.

Sources:

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html

Comment: Also I should note the cross-domain issue. Anything which is loaded in an iframe from another domain won't be accessible to you. It's a security restriction.

Comment: Thats right, but the DOM can change everytime bescause of scripts that are working with delays or similar. So i need to loop through the whole DOM multiple times... I was afraid of something like that.

Comment: OK, well, just to double-check: you know that most browsers' developer tools can tell you this stuff anyway? It's just that it's not possible via JavaScript. I'm assuming you want this for public stuff, but thought I'd mention just in case!

Comment: :D the browser's console shows each and every resource-loading error. And yes, i want javascript to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JavaScript method `onerror` to check that:

```
<img src="false.jpg" onerror="alert('Failed to load');" />
```

But if you're loading images dynamically, you can use functions like [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).

Comment: the problem: if i use something like _google adsense_, a script which is loading a variety of images and other scritps; i cant hook in to find out if there may be resources the were not found...

Answer (score 0):

```
function ImageExist(url) 
{
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = url;
   return img.height != 0;
}
```

i found this from user cichy on : [How do I check if file exists in jQuery or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript)

with this function simply do this:
 if it dosen't exist (onload) add the image name into an array. There, you will have all information

**EDIT:**

If  you want to find all images on page try PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.
You'll have to download it  [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/?source=dlp) first.
An example (created with help of NAVEEDs post on [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)):

```
<?php
$html = file_get_html('filename.php');

$image_names = array(); //store all image_names in here 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element){
$image_names[] = $element->src;
}
function check_images($array){
foreach($array as $img){
    if(@getimagesize($img)) echo "true"; else echo "false: ".$img;
}

}
check_images($image_names);
```

If worked perfectly for me!

Comment: like commented to faino, it is hard to even find out which urls had been requested :(

Comment: I updated my answer. New way can also handle images from elsewhere.

Comment: This can only parse the elements that are initial included in 'filename.php', but not those that are created via js. But its a very cool idea ;)

Comment: actually you can combine all pages:
$html = file_get_html('filename.php').file_get_html('otherpage.html');
You can use an array again. This should work.. :)