# Get list of links that have thrown a 404 error after browser loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, http-status-code-404

I have a page that loads a bunch of images.

Some of the links are to images that do not exist, and as such the browser throws a 404 when trying to retrieve these images.

Here is an example of the problem:

```
<div>01<img id="01" src="http://i.imgur.com/ydiBX0Bb.jpg" /></div><hr />
<div>02<img id="02" src="http://i.imgur.com/aObMmrWb.jpg" /></div><hr />
<div>03<img id="03" src="http://www.google.com/does_not_exist.jpg" /></div><hr />
<div>04<img id="04" src="http://www.google.com/also_does_not_exist.jpg" /></div><hr />
<div>05<img id="05" src="http://i.imgur.com/kJezbugb.jpg" /></div><hr />
```

And the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/amv3z/

Images 1, 2, and 5 all load fine. Images 3 and 4 do not exist.

As such, my dev console spits out these errors:

```
GET http://www.google.com/does_not_exist.jpg 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.google.com/also_does_not_exist.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

Can I use JavaScript / jQuery to get a list of the image links that threw a 404 error?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope. but you can loop over all of them and test them all for a width/height. the ones that didn't load will have a width/height of 0.

Comment: You can add an onerror event handler to see if they failed... or vice versa... add an onload event handler that registers the successful ones.

Comment: went with the approach of looping over images and getting width/height. works like a charm! thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What you seek seems to be already on stackoverflow.

[Click here to see the original question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript)

What you need to do is basically put either of the slices of code in a for loop.
You will need an array of image sources if you want to do that.

Plain JS function in the link:

```
function resourceExists(url) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status!=404;
}
```

example using the function mentioned in the link:

```
var aImageSrc = ['path/to/img/1', 'path/to/non/existant/img/2', 'path/to/other/img'];
var aErrorSrc = []; //Will be filled with non-existant images.
var imgStr = '';

for (var i = 0; i < (aImageSrc.length-1); i++) {
    if (!resourceExists(aImageSrc[i])) {
        aErrorSrc.push(aImageSrc[i]);
    } else {
        //Append image to string if it exists.
        imgStr += '<image src="'+aImageSrc[i]+'" alt="Don't forget the people with lesser visibility" />';
    }
}

//Append the string to any element you need to create
//If you want to append the image anyways even tho it does not exist,
//You could remove the else in the for-loop and just put the append line below it.

//To top it off, do a console log to display all the errors.
console.log(aErrorSrc);
```

**NOTE**

Do not forget to remove `console.log();`'s from your scripts as IE (ofc, what else...) is abit dumb, and when the console is closed, when it comes across a console.log it will stop executing anything from that point, or not execute anything at all.

Hope this helped

‐ Sid