# onerror html javascript not functioning as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, onerror

I have a HTML\ Javascript element im building, it searches for local files which if they exist work fine and display in the center target frame.

as it happens a file may also not exist hense i would like to in that case revert to the directory rather then the pdf its self. perhaps Im not ussing the onerror in the right contents but I cant get my code to work could anyone help?

```
<center><input type="text" placeholder="Project Nr." maxlength="50" id="SEARCHbox" name="Project Nr.">
<a href="#"
   onclick="this.href = ('file:///V:/' + document.getElementById('SEARCHbox').value + '/Tekeningen/Tekenwerk De Mar/Definitief/' + document.getElementById('SEARCHbox').value + '.pdf' )"
   onerror="this.href = ('file:///V:/' + document.getElementById('SEARCHbox').value')" target="CENTER" ><br><input type="image" src="../Images/Zoek.png" alt="Submit" width="155" height="21"></a></center>
```

Comment: what browser is that ?

Comment: you mean am I using googel chrome? (I'm not a HTML programmer so Ive been stitching togther the little I do know)

Comment: This article should help you out somewhat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript