# Javascript Is it possible to check whether file is exist or not before Http Request?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I use the simple AJAX and use google debug then find that the url is not exist...

The code is very simple:

```
var http;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  http=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
  http=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

try {
  http.open("GET", 'http://'+ip+':5000/test.html', true);
  http.onreadystatechange = onRcvData;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    http.send(null);
  } else {// code for IE6, IE5
    http.send();
  }
} catch(e) {
  http.abort();
}

function onRcvData() {
  if (http.readyState==4) {
    if (http.status==404) {

    } else if(http.status==200) {

    } else {

    }
  }
}
```

It's okay if the file test.html exists.
When the file isn't exist, the error show in the part:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  http.send(null);
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
  http.send();
}
```

So, even if I use the onreadystatechange method cannot prevent the error...

The file is in a directoy beside my web pages.

Then what should I do to combine with httprequest?

Any advice appreciate.

Add:

I have used the method 'Head' but it is return 404... (No matter jQuery plugin/javascript)

Like the picture: 
[image]

What should I do...

Is the direction of the error I found misleaded?

Comment: Are you trying out the above example from your local hard disk or is the page hosted on a server and running over http protocol.

If the sample is running from file:/// protocol, then you will not get readyState as 4

Comment: It's in Linux server, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this function

```
function urlExists(testUrl) {
    var http = jQuery.ajax({
        type:"HEAD", //Not get
        url: testUrl,
        async: false
    })
    return http.status!=404;
}


//Usage
if(!urlExists('http://www.mysite.com/somefileOrImage.ext')) {
   alert('File not found');
}
```

**HEAD**

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
>   return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained
>   in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical
>   to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can
>   be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the
>   request *without transferring the entity-body itself*. This method is
>   often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility,
>   and recent modification.

Read about **head** [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Comment: `async: false`, synchronous operation in Firefox version 30.0 and later, and in recent/current versions of Chrome is deprecated due to unfavorable user experience. Attempted use results in fail/error. Should use `async: true` with callback function for asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this function

```
function UrlExists(url)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else {
      var http=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status!=404;
}
```

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript)**

Comment: I have used this solution but I would recommend to include "http.send()" between try-catch to check if the url doesn't exists (I used a file and when the file wasn't in the directory passed as parameter then I got a javascript error)

Comment: `async: false`, synchronous operation in Firefox version 30.0 and later, and in recent/current versions of Chrome is deprecated due to unfavorable user experience. Attempted use results in fail/error. Should use `async: true` with callback function for asynchronous operation.