# If image file doesn't exist, show another one

Tags: javascript

As topic simply puts it. Is there any method to display/use another image source file if image file doesn't exist?

I'm simply drawing  elements with javascript and assigning sources to them.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without AJAX you can do something like this

```
 function checkIfExists(src) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() { 
            //
      };
      img.onerror = function() {
        // load another src
      };

      img.src = src; 
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeeah/899/)

You can also check the http status.

```
function checkIfExists(url)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status!=404;
}
```