# jQuery's include method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

As my website has only one page, and the `index.html` was getting really long and impossible to read. So I decided to put each section in a different `HTML` file and use jQuery to included it.

I used jQuery's include in the way as it has been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file/9003363#9003363) to include a external `HTML` file but apparently it doesn't work for my website. I really don't know what is the problem.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ks1x9c55t46i9fc/AAAXEGWacwSnE3WppE-_81__a?dl=0) is the link of my workspace.

Here is what I am doing in `index.html` file to include other sections

```
<script src="./js/jquery-1.11.1.min"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#includedContent").load("./page1.html");
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#includedContent").load("./page2.html");
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#includedContent").load("./page3.html");
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#includedContent").load("./page4.html");
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#includedContent").load("./page5.html");
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#includedContent").load("./page6.html");
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#includedContent").load("./page7.html");
    });
</script>
```

*I also used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript/3646923#3646923) method to make sure the file is accessible and everything was fine. So the problem is not the accessibility of the files*

Comment: Did you refresh your browser by deleting cache ?

Comment: Yes. and still Not working.

Comment: remove `./` and try it again.

Comment: Your jQuery file looks like it should have the extension .min.js, but you're only including the .min on the filename in the code

Comment: Fixing that .min part didn't do anything and problem still exist. Also removing ./ didn't do anything neither.

Comment: what does the browser console say?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yyurj0tz800vnx/Screenshot%202014-11-05%2002.32.47.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the contents of `#includedContent` seven times (see documentation of [**`jQuery.load`**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)). With AJAX, there is no guarantee which request will complete first so you will end up with random page content inside the container.

The solution is to create containers for each page and load each page inside its dedicated container, something like this:

```html
<div id="includedContent">
    <div class="page1"></div>
    <div class="page2"></div>
    <div class="page3"></div>
</div>
```

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#includedContent .page1").load("page1.html");
    $("#includedContent .page2").load("page2.html");
    $("#includedContent .page3").load("page3.html");
});
```

NB: Having said all that, I do not understand how AJAX solves the problem of the page being too long/impossible to read.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that look odd to me:

1. all your load functions run at document ready, which is weird while having all the same target. `load` **replaces** (not adds) the content of the selected element with what is being loaded, you probably are trying to add all the html contents, but your current setup would actually just load `page7.html` into `#includedContent`
2. the paths look strange to me, i guess `./` may cause errors, try to leave out `./` everywhere.
3. rather than loading an entire html page, you might just want to load a piece of that file (i dont know how `pageX.html` looks), for example you would not want to load the `<html>` node entirely, rather the content only: `.load('page1.html #content')`
4. are you including jquery correctly? there is no `.js` in your inclusion