# How to check if the file exists in js with ROR code in back end?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS,can anyone tell me how to check if the file exists in the mentioned path in js ? In the back end i am using ROR .

Ex: In the UI I enter a path where a particular file need to be exported . Before the export function takes place a check needs to be done.

Export function should not take place if the file already exists and an alert message should be displayed to the user .

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if file exists in jQuery or JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: Where are you looking to see if the file exist ? JS is only client side.. And has no acces to users filesystem at that!

Comment: @Pogrindis — It's asking about the server not the local filesystem

Comment: There's only one way to implement this: Once a path you want to check is entered, you send some Ajax-request, test it there via RoR and send response back

Comment: In that case @MateiMihai is correct.

Comment: This is better handled by the server side code that tries to create the file returning an error to the client if the file already exists. Doing the test client side is probably more effort and may introduce a race condition.

Comment: That point needs to be highlighted a lot more @Quentin !

Comment: *JavaScript* and *path* can have many different meanings nowadays. Perhaps you should edit your question and explain your environment (web browser, Node, browser add-on...), context (local file? remote URL?) and code (regular file upload, FileReader API...?)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario here the path is file path

Comment: @DavidY how do i send an response back from server to Js even if i go for ajax call

Comment: You would simply do `puts 1` if file exists, otherwise you would do `puts 0`. Then there's a method in jquery's ajax, which need to be defined by you. It's called `success` and looks as : `$.ajax({  url : "/controller/action", success : function(response){  if (response == "1"){ alert('File exists')  }  }  })`

Comment: @DavidY in response i am getting the whole of the html page not just the value .

Answer (score 0):

By adding render :test => "Value you want to pass" at the end of ror function and calling success: function(result) will fetch the value passed by the function in the ajax call.