# How to check file exists in getJSON() function?

Tags: javascript, json

I am reading one Json file using getJSON() function.

```
$.getJSON('sample.json', function (data) {
    /* but file does not exist in few cases*/

}
```

How can i check wether file exists or not before processing?

regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 5):

Do nothing (aside from having a properly configured HTTP server). The function you pass to `getJSON` will only get called (and thus only process the data) if you get a successful response.

If the file does not exist on the server you will get a `404` (or `410`) which isn't a successful response, so it won't try to process the data.

[`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) returns a [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), so you can also handle the fail condition with different code:

```
$.getJSON('url')
    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { /* success */ })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /* error */ });
```

Comment: i used   $.getJSON( 'sample.json' )
                        .done(function( data ) {
                            options.series = data;
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                   
                        })
                        .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
                        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
                        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
                        });  but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Define "not working". Use the developer tools in your browser. Check the Console for errors and the output from your log message. Add a `console.log` to your done function so that you can tell if it is running even if Highcharts silently fails. Look at the Network tab to see if the request is made at all and what the response you are getting. In short: Do some actual debugging.