# not working check file exists on server using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to check that a file exists on the server but this code always returns that the file exists, although in fact file does not exist. Can anyone help me solve this my problem?

```
var file_path = this.model.get('image_path');
var path = file_path.substring(0, file_path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var file_name = file_path.substring(file_path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, file_path.lastIndexOf('.'));
var url = path+file_name+'.ad7';
$.ajax({
    url: url, //or your url
    type: 'HEAD',
    success: function(data){
        alert('exists');
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert('does not exists');
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://www.example.com/somefile.ext',
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        //file not exists
    },
    success: function()
    {
        //file exists
    }
});
```

From here: [How do I check if file exists in jQuery or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: but i edit my code, this problem still continue

Comment: Try with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript#14691735

Comment: i try it many times, but not okay ?