# check if file exists in given URL by js/Jquery/angualrJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript), but I am getting `file not exists` for the URL which definitely has content.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1550053/000168316816000505/grandperfecta_10k-073116.htm',
    type: 'HEAD',
    error: function() {
        alert('not exists');
    },
    success: function() {
        alert('exists'); //file exists
    }
});
}
```

Actual_Result: `not exists`

Expected_Result: `exists`

Comment: please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: JS cannot reliably make requests to third party domains due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), so what you are trying to do here is flawed from the start. You would need to make a request to your local server and then have the server make the cross domain request for you (aka the proxy request pattern)

Comment: You can also try to create an iframe (position:absolute; top:-9999px) and check the document load event