# How to guess file extension with JavaScript (client side)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-extension

I have a tiny webapp, I have multiple folders in it (each folder name is an ID), in each folder there are an image that can be **JPG**, **PNG** or **GIF**

The structure is this:

```
$("#logo").attr('src','../images/article/'+json.id+'/logo.jpg');
```

I don't know the real extension of the file, many articles have JPG, other have PNG and some others have GIF extension, that's all the possibilities.

How can I guess and set the right extension, maybe using a sort of `onerror` event?

Thanks for reading, and please forgive my bad english!

Comment: Do you have to figure it out from the client side? Couldn't the server figure that out for you?

Comment: can't you populate extension in your json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if file exists in jQuery or JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: @MikeC Interesting, maybe I can send it from the webservice.

Comment: @Dshiz it is not the same, "checking" is the process that I need to repeat, I need to guess, so check multiple time until find out the right extension.

Comment: @MikeC Your comment was the answer, please put it as an answer so I can mark this as Solved. Thanks!

Comment: @alessadro Because your question is specific to client-side, I provided a client-side answer. Perhaps you could update your question if you require a server-side answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jquery `.each()` function with a check of whether or not the file exists like below. If you need to pass the json.id through you would need to nest this in a for loop. Note: I have not tested this code.

```
var url;
$.each([ 'gif', 'jpg', 'png' ], function( index, value ) {
  url='../images/article/'+json.id+'/logo.' + value);
  if(UrlExists(url)){
    $("#logo").attr('src',url);
  } else {
    //handle false
  }
});

function UrlExists(url)
{
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open('HEAD', url, false);
  http.send();
  return http.status!=404;
}
```