# Check if file exists using javascript fails

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I've seen some of the answers here like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3646914), but due to my reputation, I can't comment.

The problem is somehow the results show me the wrong one. It all outputs `the file exists!` even though it does not really exists.

```js
function doesFileExist (urlToFile) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile, false)
  xhr.send()

  return console.log(xhr.status == 200 ? 'File exists' : 'File does not exist')
}
```

It outputs:

> File Exists

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3646914 this is the same question. Sadly i cannot comment due to my reputation. And i tried all the answers there

Comment: so, what is xhr.status then, we know it's not 404.  Usually a status of 200 means the request worked (not necessarily that the "file exists" though)

Comment: Some browsers are not sending synchronous requests anymore, despite of setting async argument to false.

Comment: greater than 20o or not equal to 200, they all output the same sir James, the file exists

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use client-side JS to check for a server-side file. That won't work.

Comment: aahhh i didnt see that coming sir Alex

Comment: how is this a php question? there's also no html here.

Comment: Check what status it is returning. Console.log(xhr.status)

Comment: @AlexHowansky it should still return 404 if I run it in my console it works as expected

Comment: 200 is the status sir

Comment: Okay. I have a solution. Give me 5 mins. Need to jump on laptop cant code on phone.

Comment: i have solved it sir!

Comment: _"in my console it works as expected"_ Is your browser is running on the same machine that's hosting the code?

Comment: it shouldn't really matter the file does not exist anywhere so requesting that file via javascript in a browser should always get 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function doesFileExist(urlToFile)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile, false);
    xhr.send();
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 404 ) {
        console.log("File doesn't exist");
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log("File exists");
        return true;
    }
}

doesFileExist('/Framework/views/login/activate_studeasdfnt.php')
```

Try that. I have tested it. Sorry for taking too long. Also if your function is to test if file exists i would recommend checking for a 200 response. But its up to you.

Comment: Hello sir  ! Sorry i haven't thanked you before, it's due to my low reputation. But now, I express my gratitude that I made it out of that hole. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

try checking if it's greater than 400

```
function doesFileExist(urlToFile)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile, false);
    xhr.send();
    if (xhr.status >=400 ) {
        console.log("File doesn't exist");
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log("File exists");
        return true;
    }
}

doesFileExist('/Framework/views/login/activate_studeasdfnt.php')
```

Comment: same output sir, file exists

Comment: does the file exist? if I run this in my in my console it works correctly

Comment: add this in the else
`console.log("File exists"+xhr.status);`

Comment: still, but the status is 200

Comment: im going to post my file folder structure

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#activate_user_level').on('change', function(){
    var user_level = $(this).val(),
        content = $('#content'),
        url = '/views/login/activate_'+ user_level +'.php';

    $.ajax({
        url : controllers('ActivatesController'),
        method : 'POST',
        data : {change_modal_content_activate : 1, url : url},
        success : function(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    })
})
```

server

```
if(isset($_POST['change_modal_content_activate'])){
    $url = dirname(__DIR__) . $init->post('url');
    var_dump(file_exists($url));
}
```

Comment: Security tip 1: don't pass the full file name, you're disclosing too much info about how your system is built. Just pass the `user_level` string and then build the file name on the server side.

Comment: Security tip 2: Don't trust the value passed in for `user_level`. What if somebody passes in a value like `../../../../etc/foo`? Instead of building a file name with the string, check that it exists in a hard-coded array, or build a class name and use `class_exists()`.

Comment: hey @Fear, fixed your original post.

Comment: what do you mean sir @noyanc

Comment: check my answer. I have provided a fix to your problem with the code you provided