# JS fetch check whether file exists without downloading content

Tags: javascript, http, fetch, http-status-codes

How do I check whether a file is present at a URL using the JS fetch API, without downloading the file if it is present? Essentially, I just want to retrieve the status code but not the content.

I don't want to download the file because it may be large, and downloading the whole thing would waste bandwidth since I don't care about the contents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if file exists in jQuery or pure JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-pure-javascript)

Comment: Yes. I found that link after filling in the details of the post, and based my answer off of that

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set the request method to HEAD, which [requests the headers only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD).

```js
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/file",
          { method: "HEAD" }
    ).then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
          // file is present at URL
      } else {
          // file is not present at URL
      }
    });
```