# I am trying to open a new url page and get the title of new page

Tags: javascript, html, location-href

I am trying to open a new url page and get the title of new page.

**issue:** it is openning new page but the title is for previous page, (not new page).

```
 // open pdf in new window page 
        var url = 'http://myserver/mywebsite/Files/folder12/folder3/myfile.pdf';
        location.href = url;

        //get the title of new page 
        var title = $('title').text();

        //display new page title
        alert(title);
```

Comment: After you redirect to a new page, the current script stops running.

Comment: i didnt think of that. that make sense why its not geeting the new title. - do you know how can i get the title of 'location.href = url;'

Comment: are you trying to open pdf in a new window and display title in current window?

Comment: Use `window.open()` to open it in a new window instead of redirecting the current window.

Comment: yes but doesnt has to be display, a alert box is ok. I have bunch of pdf urls where the links can change over time. I want to get the title to see if its contains "404". thsi way I can tell that link is broken, rather than manually linking on each links

Comment: You can open the url in an iframe to get the title

Comment: Going to have an issue because the new page is not a webpage, it would be a PDF. There is better ways to see if it is a 404. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-pure-javascript

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem you have is the new webpage is not a real page. It's a pdf, you can't get a page title from a pdf file.