# How to identify a javascript file is loaded successfully in Script

Tags: javascript

I want to add a js file from external server like

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

How i can Identify the file is succesfully loaded  **programatically**(Not in the console)?

Comment: watch the network tab in chrome inspector / firebug

Comment: How do i know it programatically?

Comment: You use google http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768768/loading-javascript-dynamically-and-how-to-check-if-the-script-exists and close your question

Comment: That question is related to dymaic loading...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript right under your script tag you could do a check if some function in that file is accessible in your code:

```
if (myFunction){
  //  file loaded successfully
}
```

where `myFunction` is some function in that file

Answer (score 2):

Without using a package manager (require.js), it depends on the callbacks provided by the library. Otherwise, just check to see if a function exists, if not, try again in a second

```
// Stop checking after 10 seconds
var scriptTimedOut = window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.clearInterval(checkIfLoaded);
    alert("Script took more than 10secs, so give up");
}, 10000);

// Check every 1 second if the function exists in the script yet
var checkIfLoaded = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (someFunctionInTheScript) {
        // The script is loaded so stop checking
        window.clearInterval(checkIfLoaded);
        window.clearTimeout(scriptTimedOut);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: But if file fails to load your checking will last forever. And there is not point in checking more that once unless async loading is implemented

Comment: And I think it should be `window.clearInterval(checkIfLoaded);` (no apostrophes)

Answer (score -1):

open your page in firefox or chrome. and check net traffic(in firebug or chrome console) and see if you can see the content of the js file.

Comment: How i do this programatically?