# Execute function after script injected via document.write has finished loading?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to know when a script injected via document.write has finished loading?

```
document.write('<script src="' + url + '"><\/script>');
```

This is executed on page load.

Edit:

Thanks for all the help guys, really helped point me toward the right direction. I ended up using this solution from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
s = document.createElement("script");
s.src="myscript.js";
if(s.addEventListener) {
  s.addEventListener("load",callback,false);
} 
else if(s.readyState) {
  s.onreadystatechange = callback;
}
document.body.appendChild(s);
function callback() { console.log("loaded"); }
```

Comment: Yes, it is (add a onload event to it), but you should really avoid `document.write`.

Comment: Sure. Just `document.write()` another script directly after it.

Comment: Some versions of IE don't have an `onload` event for `script` elements. And `document.write()` is useful when used properly, as seems to be the case here.

Comment: Are you using a library like jQuery?

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768768/loading-javascript-dynamically-and-how-to-check-if-the-script-exists)

Comment: @aloisdg: That's not really a duplicate, since that one is asking how to know if a script failed to load. Though I'm guessing there's a dupe around here somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen to the [readystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/readystatechange) event for IE, and the [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/load) event for other browsers.