# Google maps acting weird (randomly works or throws error) (TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I seemingly succesfully implemented google maps into my react app (get's user location and allows to move marker), but I'm getting random error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined'. Sometimes everything works perfectly, other time when I refresh i get this error. I'm not sure which chunk of code I should provide so maybe I'll post my full map component and index.js file

map:

```
import React from 'react';



class GoogleMap extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //const getCoords = this.props.getCoords;
    this.handleLocationError = this.handleLocationError.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      lat: '',
      lon: ''
    }
  }

  getCoords() {
    const lat = this.state.lat;
    const lon = this.state.lon;
    this.props.getCoords(lat, lon)

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var map, infoWindow;

    map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
      zoom: 15
    });


    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        var marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
          position: {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          },
          map: map,
          draggable: true,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        })

        this.setState({
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lon: position.coords.longitude
        })

        this.getCoords();

        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<p>Want to export: Current Lat: ' + position.coords.latitude + ' Current Lng: ' + position.coords.longitude + '</p>';
        map.setCenter(pos);

        //marker listeners
        window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function () {
          console.log('marker dotkniety');
          document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<p>Currently dragging marker...</p>';
        });

        window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', (e) => {
          console.log('marker upuszczony');
          document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<p>Want to export: Current Lat: ' + e.latLng.lat().toFixed(3) + ' Current Lng: ' + e.latLng.lng().toFixed(3) + '</p>';
          console.log(this, 'this inside the event listener');

          this.setState(({
            lat: e.latLng.lat(),
            lon: e.latLng.lng()
          }))

          this.getCoords();
        });


      }, () => {
        this.handleLocationError(true, map.getCenter());
      });

    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      this.handleLocationError(false, map.getCenter());
    }
    console.log('DID MOUNT');
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, pos, map) {}

  render() {

    return (

      <div>
        <div id='map' />
        <div id='test' />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default GoogleMap
```

and index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBHek4tQK4jSQhVSoxw4s4c8tz_1z3xuNI&callback=initMap">
    </script>

    <title>App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Ill be grateful for solutions / tips or reasons why it acts this way.

Comment: try to declare  "map" variable as global variable

Comment: Didnt work (unless I did it wrong), still get error after refreshing

Comment: It doesn't giving error for the variable `map` you created. Its giving error for property map. means for a line with `window.google.map`. componentDidMount doesn't mean that all the scripts are loaded.

Comment: What would be the best way to prevent this problem then, benny?

Comment: You need to check if `window.google` is defined before using it. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3768867/2315280) or a similar one to detect if its defined or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install google maps as [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps)

```
$ npm install google-maps
```

and then import it on your component **GoogleMapComponent.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import GoogleMapsLoader from 'google-maps';

GoogleMapsLoader.KEY = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm';

class GoogleMap extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //const getCoords = this.props.getCoords;
    this.handleLocationError = this.handleLocationError.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      lat: '',
      lon: ''
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    GoogleMapsLoader.load((google) => {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
       zoom: 15
      });
      // rest of the code with maps
    });
    // rest of the code with react
  }
```

Comment: I seem to lose the state access in this case or cant figure out where to bind it and generates 4 more errors about fetching API, missing keys etc

Comment: oh if you want to get state access inside the **function(google) {** then you must write it as arrow function:

**GoogleMapsLoader.load((google) =>  {**

Comment: Looks like I'm almost there, thank you, just one last question I have, how to include my API key there? According to docs I should remove one from index,html, because it causes errors and should include it as "options" but I cant quite get it right, tried to include it as an object above center and zoom and before this object as `    
    GoogleMapsLoader.load((google) => {
      var map = new 
 google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),GoogleMapsLoader.KEY = 'AIzaSyBHek4tQK4jSQhVSoxw4s4c8tz_1z3xuNI', {
      
       center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
       zoom: 15
      })`

Comment: Glorious, seems to work like a charm, wouldnt figure out to include this option right there thank you!