# Simple onreadystatechange not firing even though script loads

Tags: javascript, fallback, onreadystatechange

I'm probably just missing something basic about onreadystatechange. Why doesn't either console message occur here? c.js runs just fine.

```
<span id="rightHere"></span>

<script>

var c = document.createElement("script");
c.src = "lib/c.js";
c.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log("IT FIRED");
    if (c.readyState == 'complete') {
        console.log("IT IS COMPLETE");
        ipmElements.control.login.autoLogin();
    }
}
var hook = document.getElementById("rightHere");
hook.parentNode.insertBefore(c, hook);

</script>
```

The larger problem is wanting to do something like this for fallback if a hosted library can't be reached, as shown in this answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7864346/4866743

Comment: You don't seem to be actually fetching the file, just defining its location. Docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) indicate that the `onreadystatechange` event is applied to a new request.

Comment: What about adding `c.onload`? The link you posted uses both events.

Comment: Oh, right, no onload. Worked now!

But can anyone explain why both are needed? It seems redundant.