# What error is thrown when trying to appendChild script element fails due to unauthorized

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling

I want to catch a specific failure of this JavaScript code:

```
var script = $wnd.document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', url);
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
```

When the url where the script resides needs the user to be logged in, and so returns an HTTP 401 Unauthorized error.

None of the values I understand that error (in a try/catch) can take on seem to match very well.

**EvalError:**  An error in the `eval()` function has occurred.
**RangeError:** Out of range number value has occurred.
**ReferenceError:** An illegal reference has occurred.
**SyntaxError:**    A syntax error within code inside the `eval()` function has occurred. event.
**TypeError:**  An error in the expected variable type has occurred.
**URIError:**   An error when encoding or decoding the URI has occurred (ie: when calling `encodeURI()`).

Is there any way to catch specifically this 401 error, or at least the class of IO error that would be thrown by not being able to load the script.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell if a <script> tag failed to load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538745/how-to-tell-if-a-script-tag-failed-to-load)

Comment: Since ECMAScript doesn't have any I/O, it's not surprising that it doesn't have any messages for I/O errors. :-) You need to look at the various W3C standards, but I don't think they deal with it either. Perhaps HTML5 will include something... :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
script.addEventListener('error', function(){
    // Didn't load
}, true);
```

Comment: Note the error event isn't supported in all browsers: I don't think it is supported in IE prior to IE9, and it isn't supported in Opera until Opera 12 (not yet released). Also note that the error event only fires if the script is same-origin.

Comment: @gsnedders Thanks for those details. My script is NOT same origin so you saved me debugging that problem. If you want to submit an answer I will accept it.

Comment: This does not work for me in Chrome v105