# How to check if angular is loaded correctly

Tags: angularjs

Let's say that I want to reference angularjs from a CDN but I would also like a fallback in case the call to the CDN fails, e.g. pointing to a local js-file. When it comes to JQuery I have seen examples where you would do something like this in javascript:

```
if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    ....
}
```

Is there anything similar for angularjs I can do?

Comment: `if (typeof angular == 'undefined')` ?

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/538823/987185

Comment: I feel very embarrassed...don't know what to say. Why didn't I try this? Of course it works :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell if a <script> tag failed to load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538745/how-to-tell-if-a-script-tag-failed-to-load)

Answer (score 33):

```
if(typeof angular == 'undefined') {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I just opened the console by hitting `F12` (or right-clicking and selecting `Inspect element`, then typed in `angular`.

If you get the message `Object {version: Object, callbacks: Object}`, angular is loaded.

If you get the message `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined`, angular is not loaded.

Answer (score 7):

You can detect if the angular CDN ([Content Delivery Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)) has loaded the angular object correctly (i.e. this happens if the CDN is down) by testing if the `angular` JavaScript object is `undefined`.

You should then fallback to a local copy loaded using a `document.write`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(typeof angular == 'undefined') {
       document.write(unescape("%3Cscript type='text/javascript' src='/Scripts/angular.min.js'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
     }
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if(window.angular === undefined) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For angular 2 and newer try

```
window.ng
```

in a console

Answer (score 1):

I use this simple code before starting to know if the code has loaded

```
<body ng-app="">
 {{3  + 3}}
</body>
```

If this results in 6 then it means your angular is loaded else not.

Answer (score 1):

For angular 11 you can use:

```js
if(document.getElementsByTagName('app-root')[0].attributes['ng-version'] === undefined){
...
}
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution that is future friendly...

Answer (score 0):

Or do it like so :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>(typeof angular != 'undefined') || document.write('<script src="js/angular.min.js")<\/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, this will return false when angular app has completed loading.

```
window.getAllAngularTestabilities()[0]._ngZone.hasPendingMacrotasks
```