# How can I check whether there is a Angular.js loaded on page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I check whether there is a Angular.js script  loaded on page?

Comment: `if(angular){}`, assuming the variable isn't used by something else.

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742191/how-to-check-if-angular-is-loaded-correctly

Comment: Just i try to check, if the CDN is working properly in my project. I'm using mike and cebrus answer , it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by doing this

```
if (window['angular']) {
    // Angular is loaded and available to use
}
```

Comment: `if (angular) {` why `window[]`?

Comment: Executing your code throws a `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined` exception. When checking on window object, it verifies if `angular` property exists or not. If it does not exist, it will not throw an exception.

Comment: ah, of course. Good point.