# Test fails because AngularJS has not initialized in time

Tags: angularjs, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying out TestCafe for an AngularJS (v1.6) application.

I have a `button` then when clicked, opens a modal (from UI bootstrap). This works fine when I try myself in Chrome.

`<button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open</button>`

Our application requires user authentication, and the login page is *not* Angular-based. That phase of my test works fine.

However, when the actual test runs, it "clicks" the button but nothing happens.

I suspect, but can't prove, that it's clicked before AngularJS has properly initialized on the page.

With some research, I found the testcafe-angular-selectors project and a `waitForAngular` method but that appears to apply only to Angular2+.

```
import { Role, Selector } from 'testcafe';

const regularAccUser = Role('http://127.0.0.1:8080', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText('[name=username]', 'abc')
        .typeText('[name=password]', '123')
        .click('.btn-primary');
});

fixture`Characters Modal`;

test('modal title', async t => {
    await t
        .useRole(regularAccUser)
        .navigateTo('http://127.0.0.1:8080/fake/page')
        .click('.btn')
        .expect(Selector('.modal-title').innerText).eql('Insert Symbol');
});
```

Adding `.wait(1000)` before the `click` solves the issue. It's not waiting for Angular to load. I'd rather not have `waits` in every test - is there some other technique I can use?

Answer (score 3):

You can use TestCafe assertions as a mechanism to wait until an element is ready before acting on it.

A typical waiting mechanism would be:

```
const button = Selector('button.btn')
    .with({visibilityCheck: true});

await t
    .expect(button.exists) // wait until component is mounted in DOM
    .ok({timeout: 10000})  // wait enough time 
    .hover(button)         // move TestCafe cursor over the component
    .expect(button.hasAttribute('disabled'))
    .notOk({timeout: 10000}) // wait until the button is enabled
    .click(button); // now we are sure the button is there and is clickable
```

This [article](https://github.com/hdorgeval/testcafe-snippets/blob/master/say-goodbye-to-flakyness.md) may also help you in managing all those waiting mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly mentioned, the `waitForAngular` method is intended for Angular only, not for AngularJS.
I recommend you create your own `waitForAngularJS` function and call it on the `beforeEach` hook and after the role was initialized.

In the simplest case, it can be implemented as follows:

```
function waitForAngularJS (t) {
    await t.wait(1000);
}

fixture `App tests`
    .page('page with angularjs')
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await waitForAngularJS(t);
    });
```

However, the use of the `wait` method is not a solid solution. I recommend you find a way to detect if AngularJS is loaded on a page on the client side. If it is possible, you can implement the `waitForAngularJS` method using the TestCafe [ClientFunctions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/) mechanism.

This post can be useful as well: [How to check if angular is loaded correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742191/how-to-check-if-angular-is-loaded-correctly)

Comment: I've tried this route, but I think what's happening is that because it's in beforeEach, it triggers before the `useRole` authentication, and then never fires on the actual page I'm trying to test. Our app has a non-angular login form. On login, we redirect the user to another page in the app. Unless I use `navigateTo` in my test, tc never goes to the right page. I need this code to execute after that navigation, not before the test.

Comment: I think you can specify 'about:blank' as a page, set the 'preserveUrl' flag to 'true' and use 't.navigateTo` and `waitForAngular` inside the role.