# <link> onerror do not work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling

I am trying to attach an event handler for the `onerror` event (404 error) to a `<link>` element.

I have something like this on my page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dead/link.css" onerror="handle404Error()" />
```

It works fine on Chrome and Opera but it should work on IE9+ too. I found [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html), but I can't find a solution myself.

Is there a way to do that without writing an extra method to load styles dynamically?

NOTE: I didn't tag this question with 'jquery', so please don't use it in your answers.

Comment: [According to this](https://pie.gd/test/script-link-events/) it's only supported in Chrome 19+, Firefox 9+, iOS 6.0.0, and Safari 6.0.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In IE, the `onerror` event does not fire on invalid `link` URLs, but the `onload` event does.

In Chrome, the opposite is true:  The `onload` event does not fire on invalid `link` URLs, but the `onerror` event does.

So you'll need to use both events:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="dead/link.css" 
      onload="handle404Error(this)"
      onerror="handle404Error(this, true)"
/>

function handle404Error(el, failed) {
  if(failed || (el.sheet.cssRules && !el.sheet.cssRules.length)) {
    //Failed!
  }
  else {
    //Success!
  }
}
```

---

**Example using invalid URL:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/et0g2xg6/**

---

**Example using valid URL:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/et0g2xg6/1**

**Update August 2017**, thanks to @Alex:

> `onerror` is fired by Chrome and Firefox.
>   `onload` is fired by Internet Explorer.
>   Edge fires neither `onerror` nor `onload`.

Comment: Thanks, I had recently uninstalled Firefox.  Will reinstall and troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine for me but is there an other way than check the css rules? with this solution it will also call `handle404Error()` when the css file do not contain css definitions...

Comment: I came up with the cssRules solution through experimentation.  I haven't found another property or method that works as well.  Still working on a Firefox solution and will update my answer when finished.

Comment: Update August 2017: `onerror` is fired by Chrome and Firefox. `onload` is fired by Internet Explorer. Edge fires neither `onerror` nor `onload`.

Comment: Thanks, @Alex.  Updated with your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Following solution works in Firefox, you just need to arrange function definition and function calling:

```
function handle404Error(el, failed) {
    if(failed || (el.sheet.cssRules && !el.sheet.cssRules.length)) {
        //Failed!
    }
    else {
        //Success!
    }
 }

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
       href="dead/link.css" 
       onload="handle404Error(this)"
       onerror="handle404Error(this, true)"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

**IE** When the link href is for an invalid domain url, e.g. not a 404, then IE throws a `Access is denied` when trying to access the `cssRules` property.

```
function load (e) {
  var cssRules;
  try {
    cssRules = e.target.sheet && e.target.sheet.cssRules;
  } catch (e) {
    cssRules = { length: 0 };
  }

  if (cssRules.length) {
    console.log('load', e);    
  } else {
    console.error('load error', e);
  }
}`
```