# why didn't get any error in createElement when the url is wrong

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a promise base function that load-scripts.
this is my code :

```
export const loadScript = ({ url,  id }) => {      
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
      scriptTag.src = url;
      scriptTag.id = id;
      scriptTag.onerror = (e) => {
        console.log("failed", e);
        reject("failed");
      };          
      scriptTag.onload = (e) => {
        console.log("done", e);
        resolve("done");
      };          
       document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
    } catch (error) {
      reject("fail");
    }
  });
};
```

it works fine but when I tried to test my code and passed a wrong url to the function neither onerror nor catch was called,and it just called the onload callback.

how can I get when the script doesn't exist?

Comment: which wrong url did you try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell if a <script> tag failed to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538745/how-to-tell-if-a-script-tag-failed-to-load)