# How to check if instagram.com/embed.js is already loaded in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, instagram

Hi I need to know if instagram "embed.js" is loaded within a page or not.
If the script is not there I load it, otherwise I do nothing.

The url is: https://instagram.com/embed.js

Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538745/how-to-tell-if-a-script-tag-failed-to-load

Comment: It is not the solution I am looking for. I need to know if the script is already loaded.